# Get data on how many repositories have been created from my template repository

Tags: github

I have recently created a public template repository on GitHub. I want to add a simple badge to the README.md of the repository, so that I could show the "reach" of the repository.

Is there any way to fetch the number of repositories created using my template repository as a base, and then display it in the README? (If not, is there some equivalent statistic that I could fetch?)